# What encoding does the Oracle jvm use for preference node names on Windows?

Tags: java, encoding, preferences

I happened to create a system preference node name in a Java app running on Windows that consisted of some Chinese characters and then took a look at the registry to verify, and found that the jvm was using some text-based encoding for the node name that I didn't recognise at all.

All of the node names with these kinds of characters were represented as strings with a sequence that began with "/!" (not including the quotes), and then included a number of characters that are not included in the Base64 alphabet, like $ % { ^, though some of them did end with Base64 padding sequences like = and ==. So, it does not appear to be Base64.

Here are some examples:

```
/!}-!=
/!4'6`49<"7l]`:0krpoo(8-}-#^q&8^_6
/!f%>s>o{z5qzj.k"sy78=
```

Of the above encodings, I know that this one:

```
/!}-!=
```

...is used to represent this character:

```
悠
```

...which, in utf8, is:

```
0xe6 0x82 0xa0
```

I tried plugging some of these values (with and without the leading /!) into a uudecoder but they were all rejected as invalid, so I don't think it's uuencoded, either, though the alphabet looked consistent.

Thought somebody might have encountered this before and knew what this encoding is.

Comment: It is modified Base64, as can be seen near the end of http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8u/jdk8u/jdk/file/81e87652146b/src/windows/classes/java/util/prefs/WindowsPreferences.java

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per Oleg's comment,

This is an alternative base64 encoding, replacing upper-case letters from that alphabet with special characters to account for case-insensitivity in the Windows registry.

See here for a source listing of a class providing the implementation:
http://www.docjar.com/html/api/java/util/prefs/Base64.java.html

From that listing, here's the alternative alphabet:

```
   /**
    * This array is a lookup table that translates 6-bit positive integer
    * index values into their "Alternate Base64 Alphabet" equivalents.
    * This is NOT the real Base64 Alphabet as per in Table 1 of RFC 2045.
    * This alternate alphabet does not use the capital letters.  It is
    * designed for use in environments where "case folding" occurs.
    */
   private static final char intToAltBase64[] = {
       '!', '"', '#', '$', '%', '&', '\'', '(', ')', ',', '-', '.', ':',
       ';', '<', '>', '@', '[', ']', '^',  '`', '_', '{', '|', '}', '~',
       'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g',  'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm',
       'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't',  'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z',
       '0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6',  '7', '8', '9', '+', '?'
   };
```